# If $f(x) < g(x)$ for all $x \neq a$, and $\lim_{x\to a} f(x)=L$ and $\lim_{x\to a} g(x)=M$,then is $L<M$?

Tags: limits

If $f(x) < g(x)$ for all $x \leq a$, and $\lim_{x\to a} f(x)=L$ and $\lim_{x\to a} g(x)=M$,then is $L<M$?

I know the limit with inequality theorem says that if $f(x)\leq g(x)$ then $\lim f(x) \leq \lim g(x)$.  My assumption is that since $f(x)<g(x)$ so the limit of $f(x)$ is less than limit of $g(x)$.  Or must it still be less than or equal to?

Comment: Let $g$ be the absolute value function, let $f=-g$ and see what happens with $a=0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No: Consider the functions $$f(x) = x$$ and $$g(x) = \left\{\begin{array}{lc} 2x - 1 & x < 1 \\ 1 & x > 1\end{array}\right.$$

Then $g(x) < x$ for all $x \ne 1$, but $$\lim_{x \to 1} g(x) = 1 = \lim_{x \to 1} f(x)$$

---

For a different example, take $f(x) \equiv 0$ and $g(x) = -x^2$, at $0$.

Comment: So from what I understand, there exists a function where f(x) is less than g(x) yet the limit of f(x) is less than or equal to g(x).

Comment: I looked at the examples you gave me and this is what I concluded.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is still less than or equal to. $\frac{1}{x^2}>0$ for all $x\in\Bbb R$, but $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{1}{x^2}=\lim_{x\to\infty}0=0$